# android disable seek bar for audio controller

Tags: android, seekbar

I used the following seek bar for displacing the progress of my audio.

```
<SeekBar
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:id="@+id/SeekBar01"
    android:layout_width="245dip"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seekthumb2"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"

    android:longClickable="false"/>
```

I want to disable the manual motion of this seek bar. i mean the seek can only move by my code and it cannot be accessed by any other means (Touch).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Just add touch event handler and return true, like example below:

```
    seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

User won't be able to touch and change the progress this way.

Comment: I want the seekbar to be movable only by thumb and disable the click. how to do it ?

Comment: Great! Very helpful even after a long time! Thanks!

Comment: @contactmeandroid hae you got the solution

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin lambda solution:

```
seekbar.setOnTouchListener { _, _ -> true }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a empty eventhandler for the event of "click".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
seekBar.setEnabled(false);
```