# How to Set an Android SeekBar to be unmoveable/frozen?

Tags: android, focus, click, touch, seekbar

In my XML, I've set the `focusable`, `focusableInTouchMode`, `clickable`, and `longClickable` variables to false, yet I can still click and move the SeekBar.  Do I need to actually change the listener events to do this?  That seems so unnecessary.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You need to do this from your activity or fragment by

```
//java
mySeekBar.setEnabled(false);
```

```
//kotlin
mySeekBar.enabled = false;
```

Or if you want to do it by `xml`

```
android:enabled="false"
```

Comment: Is there a similar XML solution?

Comment: try `android:enabled="false"`

Comment: This solution "greys out" the seek bar though.  If you don't want that to occur, check out Muhammad Abdullah's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020881/android-disable-seek-bar-for-audio-controler

Comment: android:enabled="false" didn't work for me. And AFAIK the android:enabled attribute is used only for TextView and it's children. At least this attribute isn't specified for the View class in the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: why this `android:enabled` don't appear in the *intellicence* of eclipse?

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo It doesn't appear even in Android Studio 3.0.1

Comment: **android:enabled="false"** doesn't work for seekbar. It only works pragmatically **mySeekBar.setEnabled(false)**

Answer (score 11):

You could create a subclass whose parent is a `SeekBar`. In your new class, override the `onTouchEvent()` method to always return false.

This solution should not "grey out" the seek bar since the enabled state will not change.