# how do i make a seekbar inactive till pressed or touched by the user?

Tags: java, android, xml, seekbar

Hi guys i have 2 seek bars in one activity and a 2 textviews. Each textview has a number and each seekbar can increment a specific textview. So seekbar a increments textview a and seekbar b increments textview b. However if I am using seekbar a i want it so that as soon as the user touches seekbar a then seekbar b changes colour to a darker colour perhaps to give the user the impression seekbar b had become inactive and then eventually if the user should touch seekbar b then it should return to its original colour whilst seekbar a becomes a darker colour. So how do I change the properties of my seekbar to create this scenario?

Comment: What have tried so far.. post your code

Comment: may be it's given here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136569/how-to-set-an-android-seekbar-to-be-unmoveable-frozen

Answer (score 0):

```
seekBarA.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekBar, final int i, final boolean fromUser) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(final SeekBar seekBar) {
        makeSeekBarBDarker();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(final SeekBar seekBar) {
        makeSeekBarBNormal();
    }
})
```