# Android How to disable Seekbar temporarily?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-seekbar

Is there any way to disable Seekbar temporarily ?
I tried setEnabled(false) & setClickable(false). its not Working. Help me.
Thanks in advance.

XML Code :

```
<com.devadvance.circularseekbar.CircularSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/circularSeekBar1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:lock_enabled="true"
        app:pointer_halo_color_ontouch="#ffd180"
        app:start_angle="150"
        app:end_angle="30"
        app:circle_x_radius="150"
        app:circle_y_radius="140"
        app:use_custom_radii="true"
        app:max="10"
        app:pointer_alpha_ontouch="100"
        app:pointer_color="#ffd180"
        app:circle_stroke_width="3"
        app:pointer_halo_color="#ffd180"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

In JAVA CODE :

```
CircularSeekBar seekbar = (CircularSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.circularSeekBar1);
    seekbar.setAlpha(0.45f);
    seekbar.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: post your code, setEnabled(false); should work.

Comment: post ur code............or check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136569/how-to-set-an-android-seekbar-to-be-unmoveable-frozen

Comment: CircularSeekBar seekbar = (CircularSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.circularSeekBar1);
        seekbar.setAlpha(0.45f);
        seekbar.setEnabled(false);
        seekbar.setLockEnabled(true);

Comment: Just see above. i edited my question.@SumighoshCharuvil @zap

Comment: I just checked the github project code and found that it is been created by extending a view class and there is no available setenable or setclickable method. but as it is view, i would suggest try making setfocusable and setFocusableInTouchMode to false and might work

Comment: its also not working. @RajenRaiyarela

Comment: Hey Guys, I found answer for my questions (Disable seekbar Temporarily). & Posted my answer below . Check it. @sumighosh-charuvil

Comment: Posted my answer below . Check it.@zap

Comment: Posted my answer below . Check it.@rajen-raiyarela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for Disable seekbar Temporarily.

In Xml, Just create a layout which is visibility:GONE

```
<LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/Mainlayout"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/seekbarblocklayout"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        />
    <com.devadvance.circularseekbar.CircularSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/circularSeekBar1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ....
    ....
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

In Java,

```
    public void disableSeekbar{

             seekbarblocklayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.seekbarblocklayout);
            seekbarblocklayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
            seekbarblocklayout.bringToFront();
    }

  public void enableSeekbar{
            seekbarblocklayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Try this:-

In your xml:
 <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar_bedrm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

In your code:-
 SeekBar seekBar_bedrm;
 seekBar_bedrm = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar_bedrm);
 seekBar_bedrm.setEnabled(true);
```